# How do I use two columns to determine whether to INSERT a value into another table?

Tags: php, sql, select, if-statement

How can I determine whether or not to allow an INSERT INTO a table by evaluating two other columns in different tables in SQL?

e.g. something like:

```
IF (
    (SELECT members_schoolid FROM members WHERE members_id=1) = 
    (SELECT events_schoolid FROM events WHERE events_eventid=10)
) 
THEN 
    INSERT INTO schedules (schedules_userid, schedules_eventid) VALUES (1, 10)
```

A student should only be allowed to insert an event into his/her schedule if he/she belongs to the same school that the event was created for, e.g. if `members_schoolid = events_schoolid`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
INSERT INTO schedules (schedules_userid, schedules_eventid)
SELECT 1, 10
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM members, events 
  WHERE members.members_schoolid=events.events_schoolid 
    AND events.events_eventid=10 
    AND members.members_id=1
)
```

When you run this query, the inner part is run as a query on it's own. If it returns any rows (`exists`), then your insert will run.

Comment: hm... for some reason it doesn't like 'VALUES (1, 10) WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM members, events WHERE members.members_schoolid=events.events_schoolid' - i also just tried 'VALUES (1, 10) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM members)' and it threw an error about syntax